# What is the name of "::" in PHP?

Tags: php

What we call two semicolon symbol '::' in php used for accessing static properties and methods in PHP along with class name like **Cars::$wheels**; or **Car::car_details()**;. Does it have a name?

Comment: It's called [PAAMAYIM NEKUDOTAYIM](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Answer (score 1):

It is the Scope Resolution Operator. From the [docs](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

> The Scope Resolution Operator (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.